# Create Rails query using LIKE that searches over association tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sql-like

I would like to write a Rails query using Postgresql 'LIKE'. I want to be able to search a column on the current table as well as an association table.

I can search the current table like this:
`User.where("description LIKE ?", "%happy%")`

I can search associations like this: 
`User.joins(:products).where("products.description LIKE ?", "%happy%")`

How do I combine these 2 queries into one? I want to return all users whose description contains "happy" and/or has a product whose description contains "happy".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And version

```rb
User.joins(:products).where("users.description LIKE ? AND products.description LIKE ?", "%happy%", "%happy%")
```

Or version

```rb
User.joins(:products).where("users.description LIKE ? OR products.description LIKE ?", "%happy%", "%happy%")
```

Comment: You can also do it like this so you don't have to repeat description every time and aslo it is much more readable this way.   User.joins(:products).where("users.description LIKE :description OR products.description LIKE :description", description: "%happy%")

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the [squeel gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel):

```
  def self.any_description_like(criteria)
    User.includes(:products).where{
      (users.description =~ "%#{criteria}%") |
      (products.description =~ "%#{criteria}%")
     } 
  end
```